# Placing a CheckBox in the Header of a GroupBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, groupbox

I'm wanting to have a CheckBox as the Header in a GroupBox but all I'm getting in the Header is: *System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox Content:My CheckBoxHeader IsChecked:False*

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <CheckBox Content="My CheckBoxHeader" />
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

This is in a simple UserControl.

Comment: Seems like the default GroupBox template has been changed. Try setting `Style="{x:Null}"` on the GroupBox and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Your code works by my as intended.

Comment: You all were right. I had a style in App.xaml that was giving a textbox as the header and it was messing things up. Thank you!